# How to show subclass model in Django-admin inline form？

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I got some models in `models.py` like this:

```
class QuestionPackage(models.Model):
    """Question Package"""


class Question(models.Model):
    question_package = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionPackage, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    answer = models.TextField()


class Reading(Question):
    """Reading Question"""


class Writing(Question):
    """Writing Question"""
```

(There are some differences between reading and writing ,but I omit that.)

and in `admin.py`:

```
class ReadingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Reading.question_package.through


class WritingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Writing.question_package.through


class QuestionPackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ReadingInline, WritingInline,
    ]
```

I found that in `question package` admin page's inline form, both `Reading` and `Writing` shows like `Question`, I can't tell one from another. and they have no edit button.

What should I do to let admin shows subclass model in this situation?
[image]

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: @lapinkoira I use 1.8

Comment: Can you check my answer and also show class Reading and class Writing code?

Comment: @lapinkoira I have all the subclass with `def __str__()`, and I think that is the name for choice box ,but not the title.

Comment: Then you have to tell the model it's an abstract class, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then in this case the super class Question should be an abstract class:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_package = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionPackage, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    answer = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

More info here [Django Admin Interface Does Not Use Subclass's __unicode__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313054/django-admin-interface-does-not-use-subclasss-unicode)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I have thought about this, but the django gave me a error, and I didn't focus on the database, after rebuild the database , abstract class works! Thank you!